# Access conversion from .mdb to .accdb shrinks file. Why?

Tags: ms-access

when i converted the `MS Access 97 .mdb` file to `MS Access 2007 .accdb` file, the file size was reduced.
Originally, `.mdb` file size was `15 mb`. After conversion to `.accdb`, its size became `8.52 mb`. Why so.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you Save and Publish to a different version a routine Compact and Repair is performed. This will clean up the Database of any available garbage space, compile/compact codes. Thus you get some extra space.

Comment: Thank You @PaulFrancis. But is there any data or relationships loss during conversion.?

Comment: No data is lost. In fact if you do a compact + repair of the original mdb, then it also should shrink in size. However, often the original database might have compiled code and other “things” lying around that a C+R does not remove. So the sizes should becomes close, but copying to a new accDB likely is somewhat smaller because of “junk” left behind. If you de-compile the mdb (and don’t run any code), then the sizes should become rather close.